# How to validate integer with commas in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Hey I have an input field in which user will enter multiple id like 11,12,18 etc which will be separated by commas. I wanna ask that how it will be validated in laravel. As built-in validation do not support this kind of input.

Answer (score 4):

If your input will stick to number separated by "," (Comma) than you can validate through Regular expression.

Validation will look like this:

```
'inputer_number' => [
     'required',
     'regex:/^[\d\s,]*$/',
 ]
```

Validation Works On: 12,18,20 or 5,10,12,12,

> You can modify **regular expression** based on your *requirement*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write own validation rule.

It's not hard to implement. Check it out there https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#manually-creating-validators